# Is anything wrong with the given statement?

Tags: thermodynamics

If we take randomly any two bodies, the one with the higher temperature will contain more heat.

Comment: Think about *heat capacity*.

Comment: Heat is energy, so even the size of the body needs to be considered.

Comment: I guess that you are using the word *heat* in place of thermal energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different materials have different heat capacities, which is the degree to which stored energy is given away (this leaving energy is known as heat).
For example: Water has a high capacity, most metals have low capacities. Now if you have samples of both materials (with same masses) that measure 30°C each, then the water sample has more energy stored. Why? Because water gives away only a little amount of its stored energy, therefore it must contain more energy to maintain 30°.

Comment: Suggested edit: Change "to which stored energy is given away (known as heat)" to "to which stored internal energy is transferred out of the material (in the form of heat"). The way it is now worded it could be interpreted that stored energy is heat. In thermodynamics heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature change. Heat is not stored.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things wrong with it.

1. "Heat" (as used in physics) is a process variable not a state variable. Interactions transfer heat, but objects never have heat: they have "internal energy" which is a state variable and the phrase you want.
2. The internal energy of a object or system depends on it's temperature, it's size (which can be measured in mass or in particles), and what kinds of internal structure they have. Given two identical system then the hotter one has more internal energy, but (A) a large cool system can easily have more internal energy than a small hot one and (B) a cool system with a lot of internal degrees of freedom can have more internal energy than a hot system with the same size but simpler internal structure.